# PyCharm doesn't recognized existing packages. (no error but drive me crazy)

Tags: python, pycharm, apple-m1

I am using MacBook Pro with M1 processor, and when using PyCharm it has a weird behavior:
PyCharm doesn't recognize packages (installed with Conda) and marks them with a red underline, but when running the code it executes just fine.

[an example of what my screen looks like after running simple code with numpy and pytorch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0RK0.png)

so far it doesn't seem to cause any code errors, but I feel it should not behave this way, and it gives me the heebie-jeebies.

Comment: I believe the PyCharm GUI has an option for you to tell it a location where extra packages are installed.

Comment: Oh yes, and I can't find the declarations via PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

Initially I set the environment only in the run configuration. to make sure PyCharm use the same environment for the IDE, it has to be set in: **PyCharm > Preferences > Project: project name >  Python Interpreter**

Answer (score 0):

1. goto: File > Settings > Interpreter
2. click on this: 
   [image]
3. then choose Add
4. then:
   [image]
5. then choose the location of python binary and click ok
6. finally: Apply && Ok
   [image]